# Kendo Grid - Grouping and logic

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a question about the Kendo Grid and grouping - I'd like to include some logic when it comes to grouping a grid. I need to group addresses by state, and if state is empty, then group by country. Is this doable? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a hidden column that has state is available otherwise country, and then set the datasource to group by that column:

```
var jsondata = [  
  {City : "Houston",State : "Texas",Country : "USA"}, 
  {City : "New York",State : "New York",Country : "USA"},
  {City : "Austin",State : "Texas",Country : "USA"}, 
  {City : "London",State : "",Country : "UK"}, 
  {City : "Manchester",State :"",Country : "UK"}, 
  {City : "Paris",State : "",Country : "France"}
]; 

for (var i=0; i < jsondata.length; i++){
  var stateCountry =  jsondata[i].State ? jsondata[i].State : jsondata[i].Country;

  jsondata[i].Group = stateCountry;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            data: jsondata,
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        City: { type: "string" },
                        State: { type: "string" },
                        Country: { type: "string" },
                    }
                }
            },
            group: {
                field: "Group",
                dir: "asc"
            }
        },
        groupable: false,
        scrollable: true,
        columns: [
            { field: "City" },
            { field: "State" },
            { field: "Country" },
            { field: "Group", title: "State/Country", hidden: true }
        ]
    });
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/aFUjO)**

Comment: Thanks for your reply - we have an XML data source - would it work with that also?

Comment: @ElizabethM42, this will work for any datasource type. For XML your code to create the hidden column would need to be modified.